# Find nearest areas

Tags: sql-server, geometry, geospatial

I have a database containing geographical areas, each row contains the following, e.g.:

POLYGON ((-9.001111 40.624981, -9.251389 40.64887, -9.368056 40.382203, -9.4425 40.199703, -9.118056 40.14887, -9.001111 40.624981))

POLYGON ((-8.75 38.216667, -8.75 38.3, -8.85 38.3, -8.85 38.216667, -8.75 38.216667))

POLYGON ((-8.935001 38.909424, -9.002501 38.944424, -9.083056 38.848591, -9.015556 38.813591, -8.935001 38.909424))

etc.

I need a query that returns the nearest ones, by providing a latitude, longitude and a radius.

This is what I have so far but, the results are not as expected:

```sql
declare
@radius int = 200,
@latitude decimal = 37.016758,
@longitude decimal = -7.930886;

DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::Point(@latitude, @longitude, 4326);

SELECT b.idFeature, a.idFeatureGeometry, a.placemark, 
c.name, c.stroke, c.stroke_opacity, c.stroke_width, c.fill, c.fill_opacity
FROM FeaturesGeometries a
inner join Features b on a.idFeature = b.idFeature
inner join FeaturesProperties c on a.idFeature = c.idFeature
WHERE @point.STIntersects([placemark].STAsText()) <> 0;
```

Any ideias on how to improve the query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if it is to find all of the features that are within a set radius of some point, try this:

```
declare @polygons table(polygon geography);
insert @polygons values
    (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-9.001111 40.624981, -9.251389 40.64887, -9.368056 40.382203, -9.4425 40.199703, -9.118056 40.14887, -9.001111 40.624981))', 4326)),
    (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-8.75 38.216667, -8.75 38.3, -8.85 38.3, -8.85 38.216667, -8.75 38.216667))', 4326)),
    (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-8.935001 38.909424, -9.002501 38.944424, -9.083056 38.848591, -9.015556 38.813591, -8.935001 38.909424))', 4326));

declare @radius float = 200 /*kilometers*/ * 1000;

declare @point geography = geography::Point(37.016758, -7.930886, 4326);

select @point , polygon, @point .STDistance(polygon) FROM @polygons where @point.STDistance(polygon) <= @radius
```

Keep in mind that the units returned from STDistance are meters and not kilometers.  I assumed that you meant @radius to be kilometers (and not meters), so I adjusted the code appropriately.